# Are scrapy CONCURRENT_REQUESTS per spider or per machine?

Tags: scrapy

*Newbie designing his architecture* question here:

**My Goal**
I want to keep track of multiple twitter profiles over time.

**What I want to build:**
A `SpiderMother` class that interfaces with some Database (holding CrawlJobs) to spawn and manage many small Spiders, each crawling 1 user-page on twitter at an irregular interval (the jobs will be added to the database according to some algorithm).
They get spawned as subprocesses by `SpiderMother` and depending on the success of the crawl, the database job get removed. Is this a good architecture?

**Problem I see:**

Lets say I spawn 100 spiders and my `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` limit is 10, will twitter.com be hit by all 100 spiders immediately or do they line up and go one after the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most scrapy settings / runtime configurations will be isolated for the current open spider during the run. Default scrapy request downloader will be acting only per spider also, so you will indeed see 100 simultaneous requests if you fire up 100 processes. You have several options to enforce per domain concurrency globally and none of them are particularly hassle free:

1. Use just one spider running per domain and feed it through redis (check out [scrapy-redis](https://github.com/rmax/scrapy-redis)). Alternatively don't spawn more than one spider at a time.
2. Have a fixed pool of spiders or limit the amount of spiders you spawn from your orchestrator. Set concurrency settings to be "desired_concurrency divided by number of spiders".
3. Overriding scrapy downloader class behavior to store its values externally (in redis for example).

Personally I would probably go with the first and if hit by the performance limits of a single process scale to the second.

Comment: thank you for this great answer. i will take your advice and start with scrapy-redis first and upgrade to another solution if we get off the ground. What do you think about [Frontera](https://github.com/scrapinghub/frontera)? it is mentioned in the scrapy-redis readme. It sounds like they build what you describe in the second step. `distributed cluster of spiders, need of remote management of ordering/queueing`

Comment: don't have much experience with it unfortunately to tell you anything, I always brushed it off as a more of a smart queue worker for broad crawls while I usually get away with built-in scrapy priority queue and manual url partitioning. Perhaps also check out [scrapy-cluster](https://github.com/istresearch/scrapy-cluster), it has forked from scrapy-redis but has far richer functionality now, also I feel it is a more "unto itself" solution than frontera for managing spider clusters